# Designing a single table for DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am working my through learning single table designs with DynamoDB and noSQL. I have invoice data with a few access patterns. Each invoice has an attribute of the tech used, and up to 5 options can be added (pre-determined options). The projects also have a type and that can be up to 3 pre-determined types.

1. Query using project ID. This one is fairly straight forward to me. Query on PK (`INVOICE#invoice_id`)
2. Query projects, based on if the selected tech was used. Query on both PK (`TECH#tech_type`) and SK (`INVOICE#invoice_id`).
3. Query projects, based on type (similar to above). Query on both PK (`TECH#tech_type`) and SK (`TYPE#proj_type`).

The three item types could be stored in one table as:

Invoice Items:
[image]

Tech Item (sample):
[image]

Type Item (sample):
[image]

This would give me three item types (invoice, tech, and type) that could be in a single table. I'm worried about data duplication and wondering if using GSI would help reduce duplication? Is there a better way to layout the items given the access patterns?

For example, could I have one item type, but have the SK become the tech and type items PK? So the PK will remain as `INVOICE#invoice_id`, and the SK will be one of `tech#tech_type`, or `app#type`. I could then create a GSI based on the tech and app selections?

Comment: Unless you have a very large number of project or technology types (which is unlikely), querying for either of those is essentially a scan.  This really isn't an appropriate use-case for DynamoDB.

Comment: The actual application has 5-6 attributes that will be queried on, each with 4-5 options. Should I just consider a RDS? Would that give a similar cost?

Answer (score 1):

You've not really modelled this correctly. In the first screenshot you've invoice as the partition key and the subsequent screenshots it's the sort key, it can't be both as for every item in the table you'll need to store or multiple times.

A rough guess as to how to design it:

| PK | SK | Type | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| invoiceID | invoiceID | invoice item | invoice details |
| invoiceID | tech#CSS | tech item | projectID |
| invoiceID | tech#HTML | tech item | projectID |

This fulfills access patterns 1+2.

Now you need on GSI with SK as the partition key and other as the sort key to allow you to get all invoices for a given tech project.

Comment: I appreciate your solution, that is make sense to me. I'm newer to the idea of data duplication. I will need invoice details when querying by tech type. Do I balance a) adding invoice details to all items; or 2) Having one query return all invoices by tech_type, and then another query using invoice_id to get invoice details?

Comment: You can do a BatchGetItem and get both in a single request.

Comment: Would I not first need the invoiceIDs retrieved from the tech_type query, and then those IDs go into a batchGetItem? So query 1 uses the GSI to retrieve all invoices for a given tech type, and then the IDs returned from that query go into a BatchGetItem (query 2) to retrieve the invoice details?